# React Native Authentication and StackNavigator not refreshing page

Tags: react-native, authentication, jwt, expo, react-navigation

I have an android app running on an emulator. I'm able to "log in" but I don't get redirected to my home screen, instead, I have to reload the app on the emulator and then I am automatically logged in. The same goes for logging out..I can click a button to log out but only when I close and reopen the app am I actually logged out, if I don't close and reopen the app just remains on the same page.

I have the following relevant snippets of code:

In App.jsx:

```js
    import React, { useEffect } from 'react'
    import { AsyncStorage } from 'react-native'
    import moment from 'moment'
    import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native'
    import { createNativeStackNavigator } from '@react-navigation/native-stack'
    import Login from './modules/Login'
    import Home from './modules/Home'
    import Nav from './modules/Nav'
    import Events from './modules/Events/Events'
    import ConsentForm from './modules/ConsentForm'
  
   
    export default function App() {
      const [expired, setExpired] = React.useState(true)
      const [consented, setConsented] = React.useState(false)
    
      const Stack = createNativeStackNavigator()
    
      const getData = async () => {
        return await AsyncStorage.getItem('@myapp:jwt'); 
      }
    
      useEffect(() => {
        getData().then((value) => {
          value = JSON.parse(value)
          if(value == null){
            setExpired(true)
          }else{
            const now = moment()
            setExpired(now.isAfter(moment(value?.expiry)))
            setConsented(value?.consented)
          }
        })
      })
    
      return (
        <NavigationContainer>
        <Stack.Navigator>
          {!expired ? (
             consented ? ( 
              <>
              <Stack.Screen name="Home" component={Home} />
              <Stack.Screen name="Nav" component={Nav} />
              <Stack.Screen name="Events" component={Events} />
          </>
            ): (
              <>
              <Stack.Screen name="ConsentForm" component={ConsentForm} />
              </>
            )
          ) : (
            <>
            <Stack.Screen name="Login" component={Login} />
            </>
          )}
        </Stack.Navigator>
      </NavigationContainer>
      )}
```

Here is my login screen:

```js
    import React from 'react'
    import { *, AsyncStorage} from 'react-native' // imported a bunch of stuff here
    import jwt_decode from 'jwt-decode'
    import { MY_API_URL } from './constants'
    
    const Login = ({ navigation }) => {
      const [username, onChangeUsername] = React.useState(null)
      const [password, onChangePassword] = React.useState(null)
    
      const postLoginInformation = () => {
        fetch(`${MY_API_URL}/login/`, {
          method: 'POST',
          headers: {
            Accept: 'application/json',
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
          },
          body: JSON.stringify({
            username: username,
            password: password,
          }),
        })
          .then(async (res) => {
            const response = await res.json()
            const jwt = JSON.parse(response).jwt
            const decoded_jwt = jwt_decode(jwt)
            await AsyncStorage.setItem(
              '@myapp:jwt',
              JSON.stringify(decoded_jwt),
            )
          }).catch((e) => console.log('login error', e, `${MY_API_URL}/login/`))
      }
    
      return (
        <SafeAreaView style={styles.container}>
    <!-- more page items in between -->
            <TouchableOpacity
              onPress={() => postLoginInformation()}
            >
              <Image
                source={require('../images/login/login_button.png')}
              />
            </TouchableOpacity>
    
        </SafeAreaView>
      )
    }
    
    export default Login
```

I added some console statements to see when I am logged in, however, the app doesn't "reload" once the jwt changes - is there some way I can make it do that? Sorry if it's obvious, this is my first react native app.

Thanks! Let me know if you need more information.

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion is that you manually redirect to Login Screen when login process is successful. So you can do this:

```
import { useNavigation } from '@react-navigation/native';

const navigation = useNavigation();

navigation.navigate('Login'); //Add this line where login is successful.
```

You can apply the exact same logic to logout process, redirecting to login page whenever the logout process is finished successfully.

Comment: This was what the code originally looked like. However, I changed it trying to fix this [issue](https://github.com/react-navigation/react-navigation/issues/9086) Basically with the stackscreen navigator, it still didn't recognize "Home" as an existing page to go to after login because it doesn't detect that "expired" has been updated. I tried some stuff with global state and contexts but so far haven't managed to get anything to work

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is you use `useEffect` to change value of `expired` variable.

`useEffect` without any dependencies will run when any state or prop in `App.jsx` change. But the issue is nothing in `App.jsx` will change when you login, so `useEffect` will not run and the screen cannot change from `LoginScreen` to `HomeScreen`.

I suggest you to use `redux` and `react-redux` to create a global state `expired` and change its value.